# Is there any *? operator in dart?

Tags: dart

Is there any `*?` operator in dart?

I am using `copy_with_extension` to generate codes, Currently I have error like

```
[SEVERE] copy_with_extension_gen:copy_with_extension_gen on lib/models/my_model.dart:
An error `FormatterException` occurred while formatting the generated source for
  `package:app/models/my_model.dart`
which was output to
  `lib/models/my_model.copyWith.g.part`.
This may indicate an issue in the generator, the input source code, or in the
source formatter.
Could not format because the source could not be parsed:

line 8, column 51 of .: Expected to find '}'.
  ╷
8 │               MyModel copyWith({ String*? myField})
{
  │                                                   ^
  ╵
```

`*?` is weird , `?` is for nullable , What is `*` ?

As I am using `sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"` and too busy to migrate null safety, I want to fork and change to unsound null safety

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `*?` operator in Dart. Your code generator is generating invalid code, the `*` cannot occur where it does.

This is likely the code generator being tripped up by changes to the analyzer.
The type `String*` could be an *internal representation* of an unsound nullable type (the classical `String` type in pre-nullsafetyp code which can be `null`, not the null-safe `String` which can't).
The code generator should emit the correct source name, not the internal representation. I'd file an issue with that code generator.